# Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
class Game{
constructor(){
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement );
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
    this.scene.add( this.cube );
    this.light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    this.light.position.set(-10, 15, 50);
    this.scene.add(this.light);
    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    this.cube.rotation.set(0.4, 0.2, 0);
    this.render();
        }
```

//Rendering

```
render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
  this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
}
}
```

const game = new Game();

Answer (score 1):

в конструкторе попробуйте в начале дописать this.render ＝ this.render.bind(this)

Comment: Да, так работает. Решение проще.